# Ubuntu 16.04 LTS locks screen despite using Brightness&Lock or Power settings

Tags: suspend, power-management, brightness, lock-screen

I installed the 16.04 LTS update on my office computer several days ago. 
I want to disable the lock/sleep/hibernate modes because I have to manually reset (power off/power on) the computer when it gets stuck in those modes.

I have used the system settings Brightness&Lock and Power to stop the system from locking or sleeping. However, the computer locks anyway when it is sitting idle in the log-in screen. I can't hit any keys that will get me back to the log-in screen when the screen shuts off.

I tried the command:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.lockdown disable-lock-screen 'true'
```

but this only gets rid of the log-in screen.

Are there any hot-keys that will prompt the log-in screen or are there any commands that will truly keep the computer from locking/sleeping.

Thanks.

Comment: Did you find a way to disable it in the end?